# How to run Heroku CLI without administrator rights?

Tags: windows, heroku, command-line-interface

I installed Heroku CLI with the Windows 64-bit installer [found here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). Administrator rights were required to install it.

Heroku CLI runs fine when logged in as administrator: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIM2G.jpg)

```
C:\> heroku version
heroku/7.53.0 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0
```

I cannot run Heroku CLI from a standard non-administrator account:
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B8HQ.jpg)

```
C:\> heroku version
'heroku' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I run Heroku CLI without administrator rights?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Chris Ok. I added code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

**Step 1:** Go to control panel

**Step 2:** Go to user account

**Step 3:**
[image]

**Step 4:** Change my environment variables:
[image]

**Step 5:** Select path

**Step 6:** Tap edit

**Step 7:** Add a new one by pressing new

**Step 8:** Type or browse the `/heroku/bin` file directory
wherever you installed it

**Step 9:** Press ok for all the menus

**Step 10:** Open a new `terminal/powershell/commandprompt`
heroku should work

Comment: Thanks. That worked! 

Please reformat your answer to make it easier to follow and more readable. It'll help more people that way.